# Namespace Errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am beginner to C++

I have been writing a simple library defined in my own namespace `core` but when I `using namespace core;` , Visual Studio throws errors

I have 5 headers

`Form.h`
`FMeter.h`
`FKelvin.h`
`FGram.h`
`Utility.h`

All the header code:

FGram.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Utility.h"
#include "Form.h"

namespace core{
class FGram
{
    double value;
    Form *form;

public:
    FGram();
    FGram(Form *form, double value);

    void convert(Form *x);

    FGram operator+(FGram x);
    FGram operator-(FGram x);

    FGram operator++();
    FGram operator++(int x);

    FGram operator--();
    FGram operator--(int x);

    FGram operator+(double x);
    FGram operator-(double x);
    FGram operator*(double x);
    FGram operator/(double x);

    void operator=(FGram x);
    bool operator==(FGram x);

    bool operator<(FGram x);
    bool operator<=(FGram x);
    bool operator>(FGram x);
    bool operator>=(FGram x);
};

}
```

FMeter.h:

```
#pragma once
#include"Form.h"

namespace core {

    class FMeter{

        double value;
        Form* form;
    public:
        FMeter();
        FMeter( Form* form, double value);

        void convert(Form* x);

          FMeter operator+(FMeter x);
          FMeter operator-(FMeter x);

          FMeter operator++();
          FMeter operator++(int x);

          FMeter operator--();
          FMeter operator--(int x);

          FMeter operator+(double x);
          FMeter operator-(double x);
          FMeter operator*(double x);
          FMeter operator/(double x);

          void operator=(FMeter x);
          bool operator==(FMeter x);

          bool operator<(FMeter x);
          bool operator<=(FMeter x);
          bool operator>(FMeter x);
          bool operator>=(FMeter x);
    };

}
```

FKelvin.h:

```
#pragma once

namespace core {

    class FKelvin
    {
        double value;

    public:
        FKelvin();
        FKelvin(double value);

        FKelvin operator+(FKelvin x);
        FKelvin operator-(FKelvin x);

        FKelvin operator++();
        FKelvin operator++(int x);

        FKelvin operator--();
        FKelvin operator--(int x);

        FKelvin operator+(double x);
        FKelvin operator-(double x);
        FKelvin operator*(double x);
        FKelvin operator/(double x);

        void operator=(FKelvin x);
        bool operator==(FKelvin x);

        bool operator<(FKelvin x);
        bool operator<=(FKelvin x);
        bool operator>(FKelvin x);
        bool operator>=(FKelvin x);
    };
}
```

Utility.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Form.h"

namespace core {

    class Utility
    {

    public:
        
        static Form* yotta;
        static  Form* zetta;
        static  Form* exa;
        static Form* petta;
        static  Form* tera;
        static  Form* giga;
        static  Form* mega;
        static  Form* kilo;
        static  Form* hecto;
        static  Form* deca;

        static Form* base;

        static  Form* deci;
        static  Form* centi;
        static  Form* milli;
        static  Form* micro;
        static  Form* nano;
        static  Form* pico;
        static  Form* femto;
        static  Form* atto;
        static  Form* zepto;
        static  Form* yoeto;
    };
}
```

And Form.h:

```
#pragma once

namespace core {

    class Form {

        int code;
        double spec;
    public:
        Form(int code, double spec);

        bool operator<(Form x);
        bool operator<=(Form x);
        bool operator>=(Form x);
        bool operator>(Form x);
        bool operator==(Form x);

        void operator=(Form x);
        int getCode();
    };
}
```

I did not use inheritance to write the classes.

All these headers implement `namespace core`

Now this is the code I used to test it

```
#include "FMeter.h"
#include "pch.h"
#include "Utility.h"

using namespace core;

int main()
{
   FMeter m(Utility::base , 100..0);
}
```

But when I run a debug, it tells that the `core` namespace is undefined.
Although intellisense is able to detect the namespace it throws errors.

Can uou all please identify the problem?

These are the Errors
The headers compile without any error.

[image: Errors]

Comment: Is `pch.h` a precompiled header? If so, it must be included first. Also, show your error messages and show how you mention `core` in the headers.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the errors

Comment: The errors are in your headers which you have not shown.

Comment: @DevSw Please post the real code. There is no `namespace.h` header (which the error snapshot references), no line `11` in the .cpp, and `100..0` looks like a typo.

Comment: Please show a [mre] and the compiler output as text from the compiler output not as a screen shot of the error window

Comment: @dxiv I removed the namespace header and cpp files,

Comment: I will put a small screen record of how I get that error

Comment: @Eugene , Thank u for the help, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio, precompiled header is usually named "pch.h" (for console based applications), but it is possible to use different name, or not use it at all. Which file would be precompiled header, if any, is determined by projects settings.

If the precompiled header file is "pch.h" and the compile option is /Yu, Visual Studio will not compile anything before the #include "pch.h" in the source file; it assumes all code in the source up to and including that line is already compiled.

So, you could write in the following form:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "FMeter.h"
#include "Utility.h"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, when I compiled the Source.cpp while keeping the precompiled header include at the top, it compiled

Answer (score 0):

So, I tried compiling it with keeping the pch.h header at the top, and it does compile without errors. Can anyone explain why this occurs? The answer given above helped but , I did not understand how.

[Compiled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do6cc.png)